# Deploying multiple applications under same port

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tcp

I would like to know how can I deploy more than one application under one port in `Tomcat`. I have two applications:

1. http://localhost:8080/app1
2. http://localhost:8080/app2

Both of them get deployed, but when I try to hit the `url` it says

`HTTP 404 not found`

Comment: That's possible if you put your war within webapps folder for tomcat. I believe either there was error when deploying one of the webapp or you are not using proper url to point to resource.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Shut down Tomcat and deploy updated war on Tomcat WebApp Directory.
- Start Tomcat and Check on webapp will it extract the war automatic or not. If yes then Tomcat works fine
- Check Exception. what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are something wrong with your war that the project didn't deploy successfully.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how can I deploy more than one application under one port in Tomcat.

Because that's exactly what Tomcat, and Servlet containers in general, do.

> when I try to hit the url it says

```
HTTP 404 not found
```

So you haven't deployed them correctly. Nothing to do with the port. If it was the port you would have got 'connection refused'.